# Non-linear system solution via Brower degree

Tags: nonlinear-system

My aim is to prove that the system 
$$ \begin{cases} 2x+y+\sin (x+y) = 0 \\ x-2y + \cos (x+y)=0\end{cases}$$
has, at least, one solution in the ball $B_r(0)$ where $r>1/\sqrt{5}$. This problem is in the book Nonlinear functional Analysis (Ch. 1) by K. Deimling. By some basic algebra I know that if the system has a solution $(x_0,y_0)$, then $x_0^2+y_0^2 = 1/5$. But How to prove that the system actually has a solution?

I want to apply Brouwer degree theory to it. 
Any hint would be appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Denote $z=\binom{x}{y}$. Let 
$$ F(z,\lambda)=Az+\lambda g(z),\lambda\in[0,1] $$
with
$$ A=\bigg(\begin{matrix}2&1\\1&-2\end{matrix}\bigg),g(z)=\binom{\sin(x+y)}{\cos(x+y)}. $$
On the circle $\Omega: |z|=r$ with $r>\frac1{\sqrt5}$,
$$ \|F(z,\lambda)\|\ge \|f(x,y)\|-\lambda\|g(x,y)\|=5r-\lambda>0. $$
So by the degree theory, 
$$ d(F(\cdot,1), \Omega, 1)=d(F(\cdot,1), \Omega, 0)=\text{sign}\det A=-1\neq0. $$
Therefore $F(z,1)=0$ has at least one solution in $B_r(0)$.